# How to convert a .m4v video/audio file to .mp4 on Windows-7, for free

Tags: software-recommendation, conversion, mp4, video-standards

Does Windows-7 already have something that does this?
Or is there a free download that does it?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat of an duplicate of: [Can I manually change an .mp4 to .m4v by changing the extension in the Finder (mac) or explorer (win)?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4895/can-i-manually-change-an-mp4-to-m4v-by-changing-the-extension-in-the-finder-m)

MP4 and M4V are essentially the exact same thing, M4V is usually used to indicate video only files but some sofware/companies are using it for standard MP4 files with video AND audio (lots of Apple software f.e.).
It's just a convention to indicate the type of content. An audio only MP4 f.e. would have the extension .m4a.
You can just rename the extension from .m4v to .mp4.